# JAX-RS: Consuming JSON POST data without setting Content-Type header to application/json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented a REST service using Jersey that takes JSON POST data and creates an object from a POJO model. However, in order for this to work, I have to set the Content-Type to application/json (i.e., `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`). What I'd like is to be able to consume JSON POST request body without the user having to set the header, basically like Elasticsearch works:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "nested_authors": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "authors"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "author_last_names": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "authors.last_name"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
@POST
@Path("/person")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postPerson(PostBody pb) {
    System.out.println(pb.getEmails());
}
```

Comment: The problem is with cURL, whose default content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So if you don't set it, that will be the type, which your endpoint can't handle. I haven't really played much with elastcisearch, but the few guides I went through used GET, and the data is part of a query parameter, that's why no Content-Type is needed

Comment: Elasticsearch also allows for POST, since some clients don't allow a request body with GET, and sending a request body with GET doesn't make sense (then again, searching with POST doesn't either, so really there are problems on both sides). I included in my question a POST example from Elasticsearch that contains a JSON body, uses cURL, doesn't set a header, and works perfectly. That is basically what I'm trying to emulate. I looked up the default content-type of cURL and read that it was "text/plain," it seems that was wrong. I'll see if this works when consuming APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.

Comment: If you want to switch to use GET with query param, or POST with form param, you might find [this article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/#more-204) useful, if you want to use POJO method parameters

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link and the direction regarding cURL's default content-type. I've answered my own question, and it works; but going to look at the link to see if there's a better way to do it. Coincidentally, I was just reading an answer to another question, and realized it was your answer. So thanks for the help with "How do I get a reference to the Jackson Object Mapper in a jersey2" as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. Since in my opinion a well defined API - which doesn't share its endpoints with any other system - should not need to depend on clients specifying the correct `Content-Type`, I created a workaround. In this workaround, I add an annotation to those resource methods where I want Jersey to always attempt to read the input according to a server-defined `Content-Type`. Whenever this annotation is present, a `ResourceFilter` will override the `Content-Type` header in the request, to whatever is specified in the annotation.

I have detailed the process in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068508/1296709).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I'm now accepting "application/json" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content types. Here's the code:

```
@POST
@Path("/person")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postPerson(String body) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PostBody pb = mapper.readValue(body, PostBody.class);
    System.out.println(pb.getEmails());
}
```

Though, after thinking for a bit, I probably should require the Content-Type header considering it contains a JSON request body, but that's another discussion entirely.